# How to load and display a .html file from an external source into a razor page

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor

I have searched this forum, but similar questions seem to deal with loading an html file from within the server.

I have some files on an external source (Azure BLOB as it happens) with public urls like:
https://blah.blob.core.windows.net/public/Legal/Privacy.html (not the real one)

I want to load them into my razor page and display the contents.

I am passing the URL of the file into the page using the querystring:

```
    public class ShowPageModel : PageModel
    {
        [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
        public string urlPath { get; set; }
```

This works in terms of getting it to the code behind.. I tried using an iFrame:

```
<iframe src=@Model.urlPath></iframe>
```

This just loads an empty frame then downloads the file..

I also tried using partial:

```
<partial name="@Model.urlPath" />
```

But this is for on server use I think.. it had a not found exception

I imagine it would be a File.read type of thing but that only support on server it seems...

I do it on the Blazor side of this project using MarkupString but Im not sure how to set this up using the server side razor page...
Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try fetch to raw htmlstring and use `@html.raw()` to render.
Index.cshtml.cs

```
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        public string htmlstring;
        public async Task OnGet()
        {
            HttpClient client = new();
            htmlstring = await client.GetStringAsync("http://localhost:5080/index.html");
        }
    }
```

Index.cshtml

```
@page
@model IndexModel

@Html.Raw(@Model.htmlstring)
```

Test
[image]

Comment: Brilliant, thanks... I have had my head deep in Blazor Client now for so long I have forgotten the server side :) Thanks again.